# Nullptr and checking if a pointer points to a valid object

Tags: c++

In a couple of my older code projects when I had never heard of smart pointers, whenever I needed to check whether the pointer still pointed to a valid object, I would always do something like this...

```
object * meh = new object;
if(meh) 
    meh->member;
```

Or when I needed to delete the object safely, something like this

```
if(meh)
{
    delete meh;
    meh = 0;
}
```

Well, now I have learned about the problems that can arise from using objects and pointers in boolean expressions both with literal numbers, the hard way :. And now I've also learned of the not so new but pretty cool feature of C++, the `nullptr` keyword. But now I'm curious.

I've already gone through and revised most of my code so that, for example, when deleting objects I now write

```
if(meh)
{
    delete meh;
    meh = nullptr;
}
```

Now I'm wondering about the boolean. When you pass just say an int into an if statement like this,

```
int meh;
if(meh)
```

Then it implicitly checks for zero without you needing to write it.

```
if(meh == 0) // does the exact same check
```

Now, will C++ do the same for pointers? If pass in a char * like this to an if statement?

```
char * meh;
if(meh)
```

Then will it implicitly compare it with nullptr? Because of how long I have been writing these ifs like this, it is second nature at this point to check if the pointers valid before using by typing if (object *) and then calling its members. If this is not the functionality why not? Too difficult to implement? Would solve some problems by removing yet another tiny way you could mess up your code.

Comment: You do **not** need to ckeck pointers before `delete`ing. It is completely safe to `delete` a `nullptr`.

Comment: In your last example, did you mean `char * meh = nullptr; if(meh)`? The pointer is uninitialized.

Comment: The result of your `new` expression will never be null, exceptions are used instead. An as mentioned, deleting null is fine, it does nothing. Also, it's generally better to not reset a pointers value to null. The last time it's used should be the last time it's not null, so having access to a deleted pointer should be considered a bug; setting it to null hides that.

Comment: "I'll always set a pointer to zero after invalidating it, so I know a pointer that's non-zero is valid" is an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). What happens if you have two pointers to the same object? Setting one to zero won't affect the other.

Comment: k let's say that when you delete the object it's not the last time you use it. let's say just for example that it has been deleted when you try and use it again at some point. it still contains the reference to where it was before if you didn't zero it out. so when i call if(object *) it will still resolve true, even though the object is true, and you may try and call members on it. your saying this wouldn't cause runtime errors?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: That will. But the same runtime errors will occur if some other piece of code deletes some other copy of the pointer and then dereference it. So zeroing the pointer is neither necessary nor sufficient. If you use it where it's not necessary, you're just being inefficient. But if you use it where it's not sufficient ... boom. (That doesn't mean you should never do it, of course. But it's rarely the right tool for the job and used in many places where it's badly, badly wrong. That's what makes it an anti-pattern.)

Comment: @David Shwartz: it is because of this that i'm wondering why c++ does or doesn't make implicit checks between pointers and nullptr. If you delete the object at one pointer, and just zero out this one, then there may be other references that reference an object that no longer exists. checks whether the pointer are 0 or not will remain true, even though the object pointed to doesn't exist. BUT, if this other pointer was compared with nullptr, or even the one you just deleted the object from and maybe forgot to zero out, will still resolve false.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: `nullptr` isn't magic. It's just a convenient way to represent a pointer initialized to `NULL`. While it is occasionally the right thing to zero/NULL/nullptr a pointer after deleting it, if you find you're doing it frequently, you're doing something *very* wrong and will get into real trouble as soon as there's more than one pointer to the same object. (There are many right solutions including auto pointers, shared pointers, and sometimes just letting the pointer go out of scope.)

Comment: @David Schwartz: So wait, that actually isn't true? having a pointer, let's say int * meh, that points to an object that has recently been deleted, if(meh == nullptr) will still resolve false? i have to specify the pointer as nullptr afterwards like I would setting it equal to 0?

Comment: @David Schwartz: heh, just ran a test to see, and apparently i built a preconception about nullptr at some point. it's in essence another macro for 0 isn't it, except treated a little different? and here i was thinking it may be the coolest thing since sliced bread. I'm just going to resume using smart pointers now.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In C, anything that's not 0 is true.  So, you certainly can use:

```
if (ptrToObject) 
    ptrToObject->doSomething();
```

to safely dereference pointers.

C++11 changes the game a bit, `nullptr_t` is a type of which `nullptr` is an instance; the representation of `nullptr_t` is implementation specific.  So a compiler may define `nullptr_t` however it wants. It need only make sure it can enforce proper restriction on the casting of a `nullptr_t` to different types--of which *boolean* is allowed--and make sure it can distinguish between a `nullptr_t` and 0.

So `nullptr` will be properly and implicitly cast to the *boolean* `false` so long as the compiler follows the C++11 language specification. And the above snippet still works.

If you delete a referenced object, nothing changes.

```
delete ptrToObject;
assert(ptrToObject);
ptrToObject = nullptr;
assert(!ptrToObject);
```

---

> Because of how long I have been writing these ifs like this, it is second nature at this point to check if the pointers valid before using by typing if (object *) and then calling it's members.

***No.*** Please maintain a proper graph of objects (preferably using unique/smart pointers). As pointed out, there's no way to determine if a pointer that is not `nullptr` points to a valid object or not. The onus is on you to maintain the lifecycle anyway.. this is why the pointer wrappers exist in the first place.

In fact, because the life-cycle of [shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [weak](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) pointers are well defined, they have syntactic sugar that lets you use them the way you want to use bare pointers, where valid pointers have a value and all others are `nullptr`:

**Shared**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void report(std::shared_ptr<int> ptr) 
{
    if (ptr) {
        std::cout << "*ptr=" << *ptr << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "ptr is not a valid pointer.\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
    report(ptr);

    ptr = std::make_shared<int>(7);
    report(ptr);
}
```

**Weak**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void observe(std::weak_ptr<int> weak) 
{
    if (auto observe = weak.lock()) {
        std::cout << "\tobserve() able to lock weak_ptr<>, value=" << *observe << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "\tobserve() unable to lock weak_ptr<>\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::weak_ptr<int> weak;
    std::cout << "weak_ptr<> not yet initialized\n";
    observe(weak);

    {
        auto shared = std::make_shared<int>(42);
        weak = shared;
        std::cout << "weak_ptr<> initialized with shared_ptr.\n";
        observe(weak);
    }

    std::cout << "shared_ptr<> has been destructed due to scope exit.\n";
    observe(weak);
}
```

---

> Now, will C++ do the same for pointers? If pass in a char * like this to an if statement?

So to answer the question: with *bare* pointers, **no**. With *wrapped* pointers, **yes**.

<sub>Wrap your pointers, folks.</sub>

Comment: well yeh i knew that. when left without a comparison, if statements check whether whatever is passed in resolves to literal anything but 0. if int meh = 0 then it resolves false. however if the address of say an int * is 0x000 etc meaning it doesn't point at anything and the bool will resolve false. if it does point at somewhere, then it isn't zero and then it resolves true. but what if you delete the object at the pointer? the ptr stil contains the address like 0x81A3 or something, but the object is gone. you call the if, and it resolves true, even though there isn't an object there.

Comment: that would cause a runtime error, if you forgot to zero out the pointer. but if the pointer was compared implicitly with nullptr, then whether the pointer was 0 or addressed something, it would resolve false when the object wasn't there.

Comment: Yes.  So what's your question?

Comment: in c++, are pointers implicitly compared with nullptr when boolean operators are omitted, like normal types are implicitly compared with 0 when boolean operators are omitted? or are pointers references implicitly compared with 0 as well, which can cause situations like the one i suggested.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis In both C and C++, a null pointer compares equal to integral zero and a non-null pointer compares not-equal to integral zero -- no matter what the bitwise representation of the pointer is.

Comment: well that answers that. thanks ephemient. you should post your own answer so i can accept that :\

Comment: -_- He just explained my answer.. otherwise he would have posted his own.

Comment: wow if you did, then i'm really sorry and just entirely misunderstood you. I'll accept your answer then, with special thanks to ephemient for wording it.

Comment: now that's more like it :P . i think i now understand why and when to use nullptr. Thanks a lot david.

Comment: What do you mean "the behavior is implementation-specific"? It behaves like the standard says it should behave. Its representation and implementation is up to the implementation (but that's nothing new. The representation of an "old-style" null pointer was also implementation-defined)

Comment: It says the behavior or representation is implementation specific..  I was meaning behind-the-scenes behavior.

Comment: *"In C++, anything that's not 0 is true."* is either misleading (= unprecise) or incorrect. A null pointer value of a pointer-to-member to what is now called a Standard-Layout Struct is typically represented by all bits 1 instead of all bits 0. E.g. `struct S { int x; }; int S::*ptr = nullptr;`, then `if(ptr)` or any other boolean conversion will yield `false`, yet the null pointer value stored in `ptr` is represented as all bits one (typically).

Comment: @dyp Always seeing something new with C++... How do you initialize ptr other than nullptr?

Comment: @Aconcagua Syntactically: `int S::*ptr = &S::x;` The representation will most likely be an offset of 0, whereas `struct S { int x; int y; }; int S::*ptr = &S::y;` will be represented as an offset of `sizeof(int)` (like `offsetof`). Usually, all pointer-to-member types have the same size, such that the representation must also be able to deal with virtual base classes and so on, which is why a pointer-to-member is usually larger than a pointer.

Comment: @dyp Ah, I see - and thus is not convertible to void* - just like function pointers - and thus the seemingly strange representation for nullptr. Are there any meaningful use cases for (other than as equivalent to offsetof)?

Comment: I think your warning on never using `if(p)` is too strong. That's the way to use `std::weak_ptr` for example - convert it to `std::shared_ptr` and test it to know if the object still exists.

Answer (score 17):

It's not possible to test whether a pointer points to a valid object or not. If the pointer is not null but does not point to a valid object, then using the pointer causes undefined behaviour.  To avoid this sort of error, the onus is on you to be careful with the lifetime of objects being pointed to; and the smart pointer classes help with this task.

If `meh` is a raw pointer then there is no difference whatsoever between `if (meh)` and `if (meh != 0)` and `if (meh != nullptr)`.  They all proceed iff the pointer is not null.

There is an implicit conversion from the literal `0` to `nullptr` .

Comment: Well, there are ways to do it. I've seen code that embeds a `self` pointer and that checks `self == this`, and zeros `self` on destruction. Probable waste of time and space.

Comment: @user207421 maybe you could post an answer with your thoughts (and specific code), it seems to me you are describing something different

Answer (score 0):

It is always set a pointer to zero after invalidating it so that you know a pointer that's non-zero is valid" is an anti-pattern. What happens if you have two pointers to the same object? Setting one to zero won't be better and it does not affect the other.

Comment: Yes, doing this is often pointless, but I'm not sure this answers the question (you may get some downvotes for it)