# If-else statement inside multi-line macro (C++)

Tags: c++, if-statement, macros

I have two questions actually.

1. Is this " if (ClassPtr1) && (ClassPtr2) " the right way to check if they are not null?
2. I want to know if it is possible to include an if else statement completely inside a multi-line macro. I have attached example code.

   ```
   #define MACRO_NAME(object,expression){\
   Class1* ClassPtr1 = dynamic_cast<Class1*>(object);\
   Class2* ClassPtr2 = ClassPtr1->SomeMethod();\
   if (ClassPtr1) && (ClassPtr2)\
   {\
       try\
       {\
           //some code
       }\
       catch(...)\
       {\
           //some code
       }\
   }\
   else\
       return expression;\
   }
   ```

Comment: You're missing some parentheses. Besides that, have you tested it? Try to generate preprocessed code, and look at it.

Comment: Also note that having to use `dynamic_cast` *may* be a sign of bad design. Can't it be solved by making `SomeMethod` virtual?

Comment: By the way, the usual pattern when having several statements and needing a block in a macro, it's usually inside a `do { ... } while (false)` block (without the ending semicolon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: No. You're using `ClassPtr1` before the check, which is undefined behavior if it actually is null. You need to first get `ClassPtr1`, then check it, then use it to obtain `ClassPtr2`, and then check that.

2: Yes, that's fine in principle. Whether the macro is a good idea at all is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

1: You can check with the c++11 keyword nullptr.

2: Yes you can!

Comment: Is there any particular advantage to that? And can you give an example of usage?

Comment: It is nearly the same, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279715/nullptr-and-checking-if-a-pointer-points-to-a-valid-object

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works. The only thing is that you're missing the `if` mandatory parentheses, so it will not compile as is once expanded.

Also, you must check both pointers before accessing them, or you will get undefined behavior, as pointed out by @Sebastian Redl.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not quite correct syntax; that would be `if (ClassPtr1 && ClassPtr2)` (the condition of an `if` must be enclosed in parentheses).
2. Yes, you can put arbitrary code into a macro. But you should generally wrap multi-statement macros into a `do { ::: } while (0)` construct, as it's the only one that includes a terminating `;`. So you'd changed your macro like this:

   ```
   #define MACRO_NAME(object, expression) do { \
   /*as before*/ \
   } while (0)
   ```

Without this, following the macro with a semi-colon would not belong where you expect. Consider this:

```
if (someCondition)
  MACRO_NAME(a, b);
else
  doStuff();
```

You'd get a syntax error, because the `;` after the macro terminates the entire `if`, leaving the `else` unmatched.

---

Additional note: you should check `ClassPtr1` *before* you dereference it to obtain `ClassPtr2`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you can do that if you fix your parentheses and don't use a pointer that can be NULL before checking if it is NULL.

2) Yes, the preprocessor gives OK code.

With the code (yours with a few fixes to make it compile):

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#define MACRO_NAME(object,expression){\
    Class1* ClassPtr1 = dynamic_cast<Class1*>(object);\
    Class2* ClassPtr2 = ClassPtr1->SomeMethod();\
    if ((ClassPtr1) && (ClassPtr2))\
    {\
            try\
            {\
                        return expression;\
                    }\
            catch(const std::exception& msg)\
            {\
                        ClassPtr2->SomeOtherMethod(msg.what());\
                        return 3;\
                    }\
    }\
    else\
        return expression;\
}

class Class2{public: int SomeOtherMethod(std::string a){return 0;}};
class Class1{public: Class2* SomeMethod(){return 0;}};
int main()
{
    Class1* a;
    MACRO_NAME(a,2);
}
```

Running

```
cpp macro.cpp | tail -7
```

Will yield

```
class Class2{public: int SomeOtherMethod(std::string a){return 0;}};
class Class1{public: Class2* SomeMethod(){return 0;}};
int main()
{
 Class1* a;
 { Class1* ClassPtr1 = dynamic_cast<Class1*>(a); Class2* ClassPtr2 = ClassPtr1->SomeMethod(); if ((ClassPtr1) && (ClassPtr2)) { try { return 2; } catch(const std::exception& msg) { ClassPtr2->SomeOtherMethod(msg.what()); return 3; } } else return 2;};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi line macros with control structures like loops or if/else are possible. Best practice (after avoiding ;-) ) for that is to wrap everything in a "do{ ...} while(false)" like this:

```
#define MACRO_NAME(object,expression)\
do { if(...) { doSomething; } else { doSomethingElse; } } while(false)
```

A do...while loop is syntactically compatible with a single statement, as opposed to a normal block or an if...else. It plays nicely with the semicolon a user will write behind it, for example. You can use it in if.. else:

```
if(cond) MACRO(); else exit();
```

Wouldn't compile with your suggestion bacause the semicolon behind the MACRO would create a second, empty statement so that the "else" is dangling. Not so with the do... while.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two questions actually.
>       Is this " if (ClassPtr1) && (ClassPtr2) " the right way to check if they are not null?

Yes, the check is correct. The macro has a few problems though (see below).

> ```
> I want to know if it is possible to include an if else statement completely inside a multi-line macro. I have attached example code.
> ```

Yes. Here are some problems with your macro (and why you shouldn't use macros in place of functions):

- You are dereferencing the first pointer before checking if it's null;
- The macro looks like a function, but it will not be usable as such.

Consider this client code:

```
if(some_condition)
    MACRO_NAME(MyObject, a+b);
```

This evaluates to:

```
if(some_condition)
    Class1* ClassPtr1 = dynamic_cast<Class1*>(object);
Class2* ClassPtr2 = ClassPtr1->SomeMethod();
// ...
```

This is most probably not what you want (as the ClassPtr2 declaration will issue a compilation error - ClassPtr1 is locally defined within the if block).

Solutions:

1. surround the code within the macro with `do {` and `} while(false)`. This will ensure that the macro expands to a single block of code. The macro will work, but still create all problems inherent in using macros to write code.
2. **Replace the macro with a template function that throws an exception** (this is the correct solution). As a (non-universal) rule of thumb, writing repetitive code with a macro is a symptom of incomplete API design (just like the use of dynamic_cast is a symptom of bad class hierarchy design).