# what`s the difference between !root and root!=NULL

Tags: c++

here is my code.

```
 vector<int>k;
     void h(TreeNode *root) {
        if(root)return;
        if (!root)k.push_back(root->val);
        if (!root->left)h(root->left);
        if (!root->right)h(root->right);
    }
```

```
 vector<int>k;
    void h(TreeNode *root) {
        if(root==NULL)return;
        k.push_back(root->val);
        if (root->left!=NULL)h(root->left);
        if (root->right!=NULL)h(root->right);
    }
```

when I change !root to root!=NULL,i get a Completely different result.Why?

Comment: These two snippets are not the same. The latter snippet exits the function early if `root` doesn't exist

Comment: In C++ you should use `nullptr`.

Comment: You changed more than just that. Your original code also looks incorrect, in that it only uses `left` and `right` if they're falsy (`NULL`), which seems the opposite of what you want (and the opposite of the logic in the second version of the code).

Comment: stop using NULL, use nullptr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `!root` is exactly the opposite of `root != NULL`.

```
!root
```

will perform an implicit conversion of `root` to `bool`, then invert the result. Here the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) says:

> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become false. All other values become true.

Thus `!root` is only `true` when `root` was `false` which means `root` was null.

Same goes for `root->left` and `root->right` of course. You can just write

```
if(root)
```

to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`if` condition implies when condition is not 0 and here `NULL` could be a macro which mostly is, and you should see what `NULL` stands for

for example it could be

```
#define NULL 0
```

or

```
#define NULL nullptr
```

or

```
#define NULL nullptr_p
```

and here is your diff, it could be `0` or `nullptr` or `nullptr_p`

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279715/nullptr-and-checking-if-a-pointer-points-to-a-valid-object)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
int main() {
    int* p = NULL;

    if (!p) cout << "!p" << endl;
    if (p != NULL) cout << "p != NULL" endl;
}
```

If you run this, what will the output be?